# Getting typescript error when pushing object into state array with useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to push new item into my initial state array, using useState hook ,but im getting error: TS2322 Type number is not assignable to type 'never'. ([...pageNumbers, i) underlined

My code:

```
const [pageNumbers, setPageNumbers] = useState([]);

  for (
    let i = 1;
    i <= Math.ceil(props.totalCommits / props.CommitsPerPage);
    i++
  ) {
    setPageNumbers([...pageNumbers, i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the state array like this:

```
const [pageNumbers, setPageNumbers] = useState<Array<number>>([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add a `<type>` when initializing a empty array, typescript will assume the type as `React.SetStateAction<never[]>`. So, when you tried to add `let i = 1`, type `number` into type `never`, typescript threw the error `Type number is not assignable to type 'never'`.

You can assign a type when initializing to fix this issue as following.

```
 const [pageNumber, setPageNumbers] = useState<number[]>([]);
```